# Indefinite integral of $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, improper-integrals, normal-distribution, gamma-function

Ok, so, I was messing around with the famous gaussian integral and tried to generalize it such that $$ \int ax^n\cdot e^{-x^2} dx $$ would equal something. A logic conseguence is that if $a=1$ and $n=0$ you just get the (indefinite) gaussian integral. By doing some calculations i got to this: $$ a\biggl(\frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{x^2}(n+1)}+2(n+1)\int \frac{x^{n+2}}{e^{x^2}} dx\biggl) $$ Which is equal to: $$ a\biggl(\frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{x^2}(n+1)}+2(n+1)\biggl[-\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\biggl(\frac{n+3}{2},x^2\biggl)\biggl] $$ And if we plug in $a=1$ and $n=0$ we get: $$\frac{x}{e^{x^2}}-\Gamma\biggl(\frac{n+3}{2},x^2\biggl) $$ And, by plugging in infinity (limit) and $0$, we get $$ \frac{\sqrt\pi}{2} $$ This isn't quite the gaussian integral, but I can't find any mistakes I did in the calculations, if anyone could help it'd be awesome!

Comment: What do you mean? From $0$ to $\infty$ the correct result is indeed $\sqrt{\pi}/2$.

Comment: @HansLundmark hi, yes, that is correct. However i was trying to calculate the gaussian integral, which is only $ \sqrt{\pi} $

Comment: Then why are you plugging in $x=0$ instead of $-\infty$? (Since it's the integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ that equals $\sqrt{\pi}$.)

Comment: oh god, i don't know how i didn't notice that haha! Thanks man

Comment: @HansLundmark since t^{x-1}e^{-t} is neither even nor odd how are you supposed to calculate the gamma function in a -infty +infty interval?

Comment: @alessandro. Have you seen the graph of $e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for. Are you looking for a way to evaluate $\int x^n e^{-x^2}dx$?

Comment: 3blue1brown just did 2 great youtube videos on why the formula is what it is and how it works.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeJD6dqJ5lo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cy8r7WSuT1I

Comment: You have $\Gamma$ evaluated at $x^2$, not $x$, so you're not evaluating $\Gamma$ at negative numbers. However, your formula seems to give the same result when $x \to -\infty$ as when $x \to \infty$. Maybe there's something in your calculations that doesn't work for $x<0$ (I haven't really looked to much at them), but never mind, just use $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = 2 \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$ (since the integrand is even) and you're done.

Comment: @HansLundmark nothing changes, in the last step i get $$ 2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx = (1/2)! $$ which is obv false

Comment: I don't understand. In the question you say that plugging in $\infty$ and $0$ gives you $\sqrt{\pi}/2$, which I take to mean that you have obtained $\int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}/2$, which is correct, and which implies that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: @HansLundmark exactly but apparently I don't, if you have time you can calculate it if you want

Comment: I still don't understand. Maybe you could edit the question to clarify what you are doing in the step where you say “And, by plugging in infinity (limit) and 0, we get $\sqrt{\pi}/2$”? *What*, exactly, is equal to $\sqrt{\pi}/2$? Do you mean $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx$ or something else? (And if you're editing, there's some other things that could need fixing: there's a missing right bracket (and maybe also “$+C$”) in the second formula, and in the formula where you say that you have plugged in $n=0$, there's an $n$ remaining...)

Comment: @HansLundmark is this correct? https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/947879074863411200/1092480819710414908/image.png?width=442&height=468 (sorry for the quality)

Answer (score 1):

I got to this, it should be correct:
$$ \int ax^ne^{-x^2}dx = a\int x^ne^{-x^2}dx = $$ 
By using integration by parts we get: 
$$ = a\biggl[\frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{x^2}(n+1)} + 2\int \frac{x^{n+2}}{e^{x^2}(n+1)}\biggl] =$$ $$ a\biggl[\frac{x^{n+1}}{e^{x^2}(n+1)} + 2\biggl(-\frac{x^{n+1}(x^2)^{-n/2-1/2}\Gamma(3+n/2,x^2)}{2(n+1)} +C\biggl)\biggl]$$ For a=1 and n=0 we get: $$\frac{x}{e^{x^2}} + 2\biggl(-\frac{x(x^2)^{-1/2}\Gamma(3/2,x^2)}{2}\biggl) = \frac{x}{e^{x^2}} - \Gamma(3/2,x^2) +C=\int e^{-x^2}dx $$ Returning now to the Gaussian integral itself...
$$ = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}dx = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}dx = $$ $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \biggl(\frac{x}{e^{x^2}} - \Gamma(3/2,x^2)\biggl)-\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+} \biggl(\frac{x}{e^{x^2}} - \Gamma(3/2,x^2)\biggl) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} $$
$$ \to 2\biggl(\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2}dx\biggl)=
2\biggl(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\biggl) = \sqrt{\pi} $$
Also, we notice that the term $\frac{x}{e^{x^2}}$ always goes to zero when we are taking the limit as x tends to 0 or $\pm\infty$. So, for every x that respects these conditions, we can say that:
$$ \int_{\beta}^{\eta} e^{-x^2}dx = 2\biggl[\Gamma(3/2,x^2)\biggl]_{\beta}^{\eta} \hspace{0.2cm} \forall \beta = 0 , \eta = \infty $$

Comment: Your math looks alright, but people will not like to see that you posted it as a picture. (No one can edit it easily, it isn't searchable.) We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164

Comment: Sure, imma fix!